# wordpress displaying attachment on single cpt with thumbnail size

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I have snippet to displaying atachment in single cpt, but i dont now how to get the atachment image size in the code, lets say.. i want to add a thumbnail size to the image, but i dont know how..

this is the code that i used

```
<?php $args = array(
'numberposts' => -1, // Using -1 loads all posts
'orderby' => 'menu_order', // This ensures images are in the order set in the page media manager
'order'=> 'ASC',
'post_mime_type' => 'image', // Make sure it doesn't pull other resources, like videos
'post_parent' => $post->ID, // Important part - ensures the associated images are loaded
'post_status' => null,
'post_type' => 'attachment',
);

$images = get_children( $args ); if($images){ ?>
<div id="projectGallery">
<?php foreach($images as $image){ ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image->guid; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->post_title; ?>" title="<?php echo $image->post_title; ?>" />
<?php} ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

please help.. thx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use

```
wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment_id );
```

as follow:

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $image->ID ); ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->post_title; ?>" title="<?php echo $image->post_title; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the code below. It will help you.

```
<?php
    $size = thumbnail, medium, large or full
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order'=> 'ASC',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
    );
    $images = get_children( $args );
    if($images){
?>
    <div id="projectGallery">
<?php
        foreach($images as $image){
            wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'thumbnail'); //you can give thumbnail, medium, large or full according to your choice
<?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```